# How can I obtain root access inside Daydream shell?

Tags: rooting, daydream

I am trying to get familiarize with the Daydream VR adb shell command, but I can't get to find for the right documentation. How can I obtain root privileges once I have done:

> adb shell

I used the following command to see if root or sudo was an actual command

> ls /system/bin

Comment: On stock Android, you cannot.

Comment: Is there any way I can unstock it?